# Firebug shows CSS source code as located in "wp-login.php #3 (line 25)". Can't find this file

Tags: php, css, duplicates, firebug

A new client recently contacted me to do some updates to her wordpress website, after her webhost updated her version of wordpress due to security issues. The update disrupted some code on the login page of the site so that it displayed incorrectly. I went in and removed the referenced images for the login logo and background and then tried to find the source code. When I inspected the page with firebug I got the following:

```
 #login {
    background-image: url("http://www.descaid.com/wpcontent/themes/oceanic/images/login.png") >!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 500px !important;
    padding-right: 7px;
    width: 600px !important;
}
```

This chunk of code needed to be removed as it was overriding other rules, so I, of course, looked to the right of this block of code to see what stylesheet was being referenced, or if it was something in the custom css plugin or whatever. Firebug indicated that this code was on line 25 of "wp-login.php #3". #3? What does that mean? I opened the wp-login.php file and couldn't find this code anywhere in it. It was not in the style.css file for the theme, either. I did several google searches and hunted and pecked around in the files for about 3 hours to no avail and I'm now pretty exasperated. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The page in question is: http://descaid.com/wp-login.php

It seems like this can't be some duplicate/triplicate php file, but that the code is being referenced through the php file from somewhere, I just can't figure out where.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress minifies all the CSS-files automatically. These files are located in the directory `wp-content/themes/[theme]/`. The easies solution would be to just open all of the CSS-files and look for the reference.

These vary from template to template, but beginning with `style.css` could be smart.

Comment: yeah, no. I've done that already. The code isn't in any of the theme css files. It's not in any of the plugins' css files, OR in the wp admin css files. The only thing I can think of is that some css was coded into a php file that's being referenced somewhere? Also, what do you mean "minifies"? Is that the what the #3 portion of the "wp-login.php #3" refers to? I am confused, I think.

Answer (score 0):

It means the relevant css is located in the source code in `<style>..</style>` tags and not inside this file as you think.

Comment: I found it in the theme functions php file! WOO! All better!

Answer (score 0):

It is likely being generated by one of your WordPress plug-ins. You could disable all your plug-ins and see if that bit of CSS disappears. If so, turn each plug-in back on one at a time until it comes back. That will at least narrow your search to files in that plug-ins folder.